# Parse Error While Opening a dynamic Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my first post here. I am doing a college project and I am stuck in an error.

I am building an e-learning website in ASP.net and they are static pages. Now, when I am opening a contact-us form it is throwing me an error.

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSk7f.png)

Contact us form is in another folder.

[Link page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lgkD.png)

I am a noob :( Please explain me in easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`The error you are getting means that there is no file called `default.aspx.cs` in the same directory as your `default.aspx` file.
Please make sure that this file exists. 
You may have deleted it, or moved it to a different location.

Your IIS is trying to link the `default.aspx.cs`, which is the code file, to the default.aspx file, which is your `HTML` file, which uses the code.

You can see the link between the files at the top level declarations in your `ASPX` file:
**"Codefile = default.aspx.cs"**

If you cannot file the `default.aspx.cs` file, I suggest you re-create the `ASPX` file using your development editor. This will create the `default.aspx.cs` file automatically under your `ASPX` file.

**From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx):**

> The code-behind page model for Web Forms allows you to keep the markup
>   in one file—the .aspx file—and the programming code in another file.
>   The name of the code file varies according to what programming
>   language you are using. For example, if you are working with a page
>   named SamplePage, the markup is in the file SamplePage.aspx and the
>   code is in a file named SamplePage.aspx.vb (for Visual Basic) and
>   SamplePage.aspx.cs (for C#).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is just because I have name the file as index.aspx ??? Just because the .cs file is already present

Comment: Please read my answer - you need to check for the '.cs' file called default.aspx.cs

Comment: Check this one out I am not getting the .cs file but in file manager it is present :(  [![2.png](https://s15.postimg.org/87ho3med7/image.png)](https://postimg.org/image/z5bl5cz07/)

Answer (score 0):

Well! The issues was I didn't selected the C# and my project was on vb. This is the reason why it thrown me that error.

If this error comes we need to make sure what files we are having and in which language we are making project :)